# Cannot login as root to centos server

Tags: centos, ssh, root, pam, permissions

I used to login as `ssh root@servip` with a password authentication into my CentOS 6 server.

I am not sure if what I have done has caused this, but while trying to get over my problem of accessing webmin remotely I followed the following [tutorial](http://kiteplans.info/2012/04/06/two-factor-ssh-virtualmin-authentication-google-authenticator/) until I reached:

adding auth required `pam_google_authenticator.so` into `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Then by mistake, I have closed the ssh session. When I tried to login in back with the usual password, I get: Permission denied, please try again error. How can I get over this problem?

I don't have a physical access to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to the second ssh session that you should have opened, and fix it. The howto did explicitly warn you to do this, exactly because of the possibility of something like this happening.

At this point the **only** way you can recover is via the system console. If you don't have remote access to the console, e.g. with DRAC, iLO, IPMI, etc., you will have to physically visit the server.

Comment: and what exactly needs to be done physically to restore access, did adding pam_google_authenticator.so to the /etc/pam.d/sshd cause this? thanks

Comment: Either undo your changes, or finish setting it up. Your choice.

Comment: Ok, I have physical access to the server now, what do I need to do regain the access to the server, just remove auth required pam_google_authenticator.so from /etc/pam.d/sshd (I stopped there when following the tutorial) so I can regain ssh access? that's all ?

Comment: See my previous comment.